# Cmake builds add_subdirectory if add_library(.. STATIC) follows after it, but not if I put SHARED

Tags: c++, build, cmake

My `CMakeLists.txt` look like this:

```
add_subdirectory(../third_party/JRTPLIB ../third_party/JRTPLIB)
include_directories(../third_party/JRTPLIB/src) #generated from cmakelists of the subdirectory above

...
add_library(myRtspClient STATIC ${SOURCES})
```

If `STATIC` is present, then it builds `third_party/JRTPLIB` first, and then builds `myRtspClient`. However, if I change it to `SHARED`, then it starts building `myRtspClient` first and fails because it depends on generated include files from `third_party/JRTPLIB`.

What kind of behavior is this? Is there a way to force the build of `third_party/JRTPLIB` or at least the file generation? (that is, run `cmake` but not `make`)

I'd normally put all my github tree at the exact moment of the problem but I'd have to upload lots os files (really a lot of them). I believe the problem can be understood with just these lines.

Comment: `add_dependencies(myRtspClient JRTPLIB)`.

Comment: You should adjust dependencies between targets, which produces files and uses them. Order, in which targets creation appears in `CMakeLists.txt`, doesn't correlate with the order of building those targets.

Comment: @arrowd how can the compiler know what JRTPLIB means if I didn't give it a name? It just picks the folder name?

Comment: You need to open `../third_party/JRTPLIB/CMakeLists.txt` and find out the name of the target you want to be built first. I just assumed it is named JRTPLIB.

Comment: @arrowd problem is that the targets inside JRTPLIB are not always guaranteed to run, they depend on some variables. So there's no realiable way to depend on a target. Is there a way to just build everything from `../third_party/JRTPLIB/CMakeLists.txt` first?

Comment: Yes, make a distinct `cmake` invocation for it and built/install it separately. This is how it usually works, by the way.

Comment: @arrowd problem is that gradle for android, as far as I know, only let me specify one cmakelists file